# Installing tigervnc in ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, vnc

I need to install TigerVNC in ArchLinux.

Comment: There is a [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tigervnc): why don't you just follow the instructions there?

Comment: I could complete the installation, But I am not getting the GUI. Only a black screen appears.

Answer (score 3):

Is in the official repositories, just run `pacman -S tigervnc` and it's done. 
See the Arch Linux wiki for more details

[Vncserver Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vncserver)